# Python pandas resample to period that doesn't subdivide into a 24 hr period

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, pandas-resample

I have a pandas dataframe with high frequency (second or minutely) stock data.

```
e.g. 
                           Date      Time     Open  ...      Low    Close  Volume
DT                                                  ...                          
2020-10-09 09:30:00  10/09/2020  09:30:00  3432.50  ...  3432.25  3432.50      37
2020-10-09 09:30:01  10/09/2020  09:30:01  3432.50  ...  3432.25  3432.50       8
2020-10-09 09:30:02  10/09/2020  09:30:02  3432.50  ...  3432.25  3432.50      11
2020-10-09 09:30:03  10/09/2020  09:30:03  3432.25  ...  3432.25  3432.50      11
2020-10-09 09:30:04  10/09/2020  09:30:04  3432.25  ...  3432.25  3432.75     134
                        ...       ...      ...  ...      ...      ...     ...
2020-10-14 15:59:53  10/14/2020  15:59:53  3461.25  ...  3461.25  3461.50      59
2020-10-14 15:59:56  10/14/2020  15:59:56  3461.50  ...  3461.25  3461.50      61
2020-10-14 15:59:57  10/14/2020  15:59:57  3461.25  ...  3461.00  3461.75      54
2020-10-14 15:59:58  10/14/2020  15:59:58  3461.50  ...  3461.50  3461.50      25
2020-10-14 15:59:59  10/14/2020  15:59:59  3461.50  ...  3461.50  3461.75      16
```

I can easily resample this data into minute periods that subdivide evenly into 24 hours (or 1440 minutes/day).

```
rule = '60T'
 df = df.resample(rule, closed='right', label='right').agg(
    {'Open': 'first',
     'High': 'max',
     'Low': 'min',
     'Close': 'last',
     'Volume': 'sum'
     }).dropna()
```

How do you do this for a period that doesn't divide evenly into 1440 minutes/day?
e.g. rule = '65T'

Typical US stock data goes from 9:30 to 16:00 ET.
For the 65 minute bars, I'd want the following period's resampled:

```
09:30-10:35
10:35-11:40
11:40-12:45
12:45-13:50
13:50-14:55
14:55-16:00
```

Answer (score 1):

We can [`resample`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.resample.html)  by setting the optional parameter `origin` to the starting value in datetime index `DT`

From the documentation of [`resample`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.resample.html) `origin` is

> The timestamp on which to adjust the grouping. The timezone of origin
> must match the timezone of the index.

So in-order to adjust the grouping to start from `9:30` we set the value of origin to the starting timestamp in the datetime index i.e. `2020-10-09 09:30:00`

In addition to this we also need to set the value of optional parameter `closed` to `left` and `label` to `left`

```
d = {'Open': 'first', 'High': 'max', 'Low': 'min',
     'Close': 'last', 'Volume': 'sum'}

df.resample(rule='65T', 
            closed='left', label='left',
            origin=df.index.min()).agg(d).dropna()
```

Sample output (for illustration only)

```
                       Open    High      Low   Close  Volume
DT                                                          
2020-10-09 09:30:00  3432.5  3432.5  3432.25  3432.5  2405.0 # 09:30-10:35
2020-10-09 10:35:00  3432.5  3432.5  3432.25  3432.5  2405.0 # 10:35-11:40
2020-10-09 11:40:00  3432.5  3432.5  3432.25  3432.5  2405.0 # 11:40-12:45
2020-10-09 12:45:00  3432.5  3432.5  3432.25  3432.5  2405.0 # 12:45-13:50
2020-10-09 13:50:00  3432.5  3432.5  3432.25  3432.5  2405.0 # 13:50-14:55
2020-10-09 14:55:00  3432.5  3432.5  3432.25  3432.5  2405.0 # 14:55-16:00
```

Comment: This resamples the df properly for data for that first day. But on the next day it doesn't. The next day shows DT at 09:00, 10:35, etc.